# Return part of list in which I matched mouse position to coordinates in python

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a chess program and as such need the program to tell me what piece I have clicked on. So far it tells me if I've clicked on any piece at all, by matching rounded mouse x and y coordinates to a list of current piece coordinates. However, the program doesn't know what exact piece I've clicked, and I'm wondering if using a while loop I can make the loop end when a piece is found, and print/store the section of the list I was on when I found a matching piece to my mouse coords.

Currently I've got this code, which should be a good starting point for my problem

```
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            mousepos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            #rounddown80 is a function to round down mouse coords to multiple of 80
            roundedmouse1 = roundup80(mousepos[0])
            roundedmouse2 = roundup80(mousepos[1])
            #print(roundedmouse1,roundedmouse2)
            mousecoords = [roundedmouse1,roundedmouse2]
            #print(mousecoords)
            foundpiece = False
            while foundpiece == False:
                for x in piecespositions:
                    if x[0] == mousecoords[0] and x[1] == mousecoords[1]:
                        print("Great job you clicked a piece")
                        foundpiece = True
```

And my piecepositions list looks like

```
piecespositions = [queenblackpos,kingblackpos,bishop1blackpos,bishop2blackpos,knight1blackpos,knight2blackpos,
```

etc for all pieces, and queenblackpos for example would be [80,160]

Comment: Since you have the exact dimensions of the chessboard and each square, you can easily wrote a function to transform your mouse coordinates to square coordinate in the board. Like f(80, 60) = J5 in chessboard. After that if you keep record of each piece in a 2D array you can get what piece is clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of what piece you are on inside the while loop, either in `for i in range(0,len(piecepositions))` or with a variable that increases.
For example something like this:

```
  while foundpiece == False:
    index=0 #Reset index before checking all pieces
    for x in piecespositions:
        if x[0] == mousecoords[0] and x[1] == mousecoords[1]:
                 print("Great job you clicked a piece")
                 foundpiece = True
        
                 found_pos=x #store position of the piece that was found
           index=index+1 #Keep adding to index to know which piece was found
    pygame.display.flip() #Update the window 
  print (f"Piece found in {index}: {found_pos}") #print the position of the piece as well as what is its index in the list.
```

This will store the position of the piece that was found in `found_pos` and keep track of which piece is being checked at the moment using `index` var. After the while loop ends it prints out the position of the piece and the index of that piece in the list.

Do note though, during the while loop the script will be "stuck" until the while is finished, so it will be unable to update the window during the piece check therefore the game will freeze. So to solve this, you have to add `pygame.display.flip()` inside the while.

Answer (score -1):

I did something like this. Hope that it will help You:

```
square_s = 160 # square(tile) size - you can pass your value
letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"] # letters used in pos symbols

# match each tile on board to the right cords symbol and value(x, y)
def matchSqrCords(sqr_s, letters):
    positions = [] # matched positions
    for y in range(8): # for each row on the board
        for x in range(8): # for each column(tile in a row) on the board
            pos = ["", 0, 0] # curr position
            pos[0] += letters[y] # add letter prefix to pos symbol
            pos[0] += str(x + 1) # add number prefix to pos symbol
            pos[1] = sqr_s*(x + 1) # calc max x range of a tile
            pos[2] = sqr_s*(y + 1) # calc max y range of a tile
            positions.append(pos) # add matched pos to list
    return positions # return list with matched positions

def checkPosition(given_cords, cords, sqr_s):
    # check if typed values are on the board
    if given_cords[0] > sqr_s * 8 or given_cords[1] > sqr_s * 8:
    return "Cords not on the board!"
    else:
        for cord in cords: # check all cords
            # check if given cords x value is in range of curr cord
            if given_cords[0] <= cord[1]  and given_cords[0] > cord[1] - sqr_s:
                # check if given cords y value is in range of curr cord
                if given_cords[1] <= cord[2]  and given_cords[1] > cord[2] - sqr_s:
                    return cord[0] # return symbol of the found cord

matched_pos = matchSqrCords(square_s, letters=letters)
print(checkPosition([192, 569], matched_pos, square_s))
```